# How to evaluate $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\log(z)}{z}e^{zt}\,dz$

Tags: contour-integration

I am trying to compute
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\log s}{s}e^{st}\,ds$$
in relation to
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{-\gamma-\log s}{s}\right\}$$
which certainly evaluates to $\log t$. But the integrand "has no poles" according to Wolfram Alpha. So how could I compute this integral without using the residue theorem? Do I have to expand $\log s$ into it's power series involving the harmonic numbers? Or am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the function $F(s)=\frac{\log(s)}{s}$ has a branch point at $s=0$.  Therefore, we choose the branch cut that extends from $s=0$ to $-\infty$.

Then, we deform the Bromwich contour with the classical keyhole contour along the negative real axis.  Applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we find that for $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
2\pi i\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}(t)&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\log(s-i0^+)}{s}e^{st}\,ds\right.\\\\
&+\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\log(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})}{\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}e^{\varepsilon e^{i\phi}t}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&\left.-\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\log(s+0^+)}{s}e^{st}\,ds\right)\\\\
&=i2\pi \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\log(\varepsilon)+\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{s}\,ds+O\left(\varepsilon\log(\varepsilon)\right)\right)\\\\
&=i2\pi \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\log(\varepsilon)(1-e^{-\varepsilon t})+\int_\varepsilon^\infty e^{-st}\log(s)\,ds\right)\\\\
&=i2\pi \int_0^\infty te^{-st}\log(s)\,ds\\\\
&=i2\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-s}(\log(s)-\log(t))\,ds\\\\
&=i2\pi(-\gamma-\log(t))
\end{align}$$

Dividing by $2\pi i$, we find that

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}(t)=-\gamma-\log(t)$$

Comment: Hey Mark - is the branch cut for the logarithm always chosen as $-\infty$ to $0$ for the Bromwich contour? If so, is this because we must close the contour on the left due to the function we are integrating being analytic over the non-negative part of the plane?

Comment: It does not need to be taken along the negative real axis, but it (i) cannot cross the Bromwich path, (ii) must originate at $0$, and (iii) terminate at the point at infinity.  But the contour need not be a linear path.

Comment: Is the Bromwich path the strip along $\gamma-i\infty$ to $\gamma+i\infty$? Or does it also include closing the contour of that line to the left? Can you give an example of a different path that can be taken?

Comment: The Bromwich path is the strip from $\gamma-i\infty$ to $\gamma+i\infty$, for $\gamma>0$, and all of the singularites of $F(s)$ lie in the plane $|s|<\gamma$.  The branch cut is any contour from $0$ to the point at $\infty$ provided that the contour does not intersect the Bromwich path.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The integration is performed by "*closing*" the contour with a key-hole one which takes care of the $\ds{\ln}$-branch cut along $\ds{\left(-\infty,0\right]}$. Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\ln\pars{s} \over s}\expo{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,&
-\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}
{\ln\pars{-s} + \ic\pi \over s}\expo{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{-\pi}^{-\pi}{\ln\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\theta \over
\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}
\,{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &
-\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\infty}
{\ln\pars{-s} - \ic\pi \over s}\expo{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,&
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{s} + \ic\pi \over s}\expo{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
\ln\pars{\epsilon}
\\[2mm] &\ -\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{s} - \ic\pi \over s}\expo{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}
{\expo{-ts} \over s}\,\dd s + \ln\pars{\epsilon}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
\bracks{-\ln\pars{\epsilon} -\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\ln\pars{s}\bracks{\expo{-ts}\pars{-t}}
\dd s} + \ln\pars{\epsilon}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\Large\to}\,\,\,&
t\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{s}\expo{-ts}\,\dd s =
t\bracks{\nu^{1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{\nu}\expo{-ts}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{\nu^{1}}t^{-\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{\nu}\expo{-s}\,\dd s
=
\bracks{\nu^{1}}t^{-\nu}\,\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{t} + \Psi\pars{1} = \bbx{-\ln\pars{t} - \gamma} \\ &\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solution Dr. Marin! It was helpful.

Comment: @user143 You're welcome. It's nice  that it was useful !!!.

Comment: I am just realizing --  why do we assume the integrals over the large semi-circlular arcs, say $C_{R^+}$ and $C_{R^-}$ go to zero? Is there a rule for this or did you estimate?

Comment: @user143 The main point is that $\displaystyle \mathrm{e}^{ts} \to \color{red}{0}$ when $\displaystyle  \left\vert s\right\vert \to \infty\ \underline{because}\
{\large t > 0}$. In that case we have $\displaystyle\Re\left(s\right) \color{red}{< 0}$.

Comment: Ohh ok, thanks so much!